# Как сделать перенос всего слова, а не части?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу, чтобы мои слова в тексте в случае необходимости переноса начинались со следующей строки, а не переносились наполовину. Вижу, что так реализовано на всех адекватных сайтах, но не могу понять как это сделать в [css](/questions/tagged/css).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы сделали, чтобы слова переносились? Это же не просто так. Тут и компонент грамматики задействован, и выравнивание текста у вас по обоим краям. В русскоязычных текстах, кстати, принято делать перенос по слогам в большинстве случаев.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если погуглить, то можно всё найти. Один из этих вариантов:

```
-ms-hyphens: none;
-webkit-hyphens: none;
hyphens: none;
```

Поищите в коде слово `hyphens`.

[CSS hyphens Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_hyphens.php)